# Execution failed for task ':react-native-background-job:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. while executing react-native-background-job?

Tags: android, gradle, react-native, androidx

While making build of react native app I get the following error..I have attached the errors and gradle files below. I have also try to migrate to androidX with enableJetifier and useAndroidX being both true and clean gradle multiple times but still no luck.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-background-job:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

Errors:

```
> Task :react-native-background-job:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Projects\Getz New\app\node_modules\react-native-background-job\android\src\main\java\com\pilloxa\backgroundjob\ReactNativeEventStarter.java:7: error: package android.support.annotation does not exist
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
                                 ^
C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Projects\Getz New\app\node_modules\react-native-background-job\android\src\main\java\com\pilloxa\backgroundjob\BackgroundJobModule.java:7: error: package android.support.annotation does not exist
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
                                 ^
C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Projects\Getz New\app\node_modules\react-native-background-job\android\src\main\java\com\pilloxa\backgroundjob\ExactJob.java:6: error: package android.support.annotation does not exist
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
                                 ^
C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Projects\Getz New\app\node_modules\react-native-background-job\android\src\main\java\com\pilloxa\backgroundjob\Utils.java:3: error: package android.support.annotation does not exist
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
                                 ^
C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Projects\Getz New\app\node_modules\react-native-background-job\android\src\main\java\com\pilloxa\backgroundjob\ReactNativeEventStarter.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
  ReactNativeEventStarter(@NonNull Context context) {
                           ^
  symbol:   class NonNull
  location: class ReactNativeEventStarter
C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Projects\Getz New\app\node_modules\react-native-background-job\android\src\main\java\com\pilloxa\backgroundjob\ReactNativeEventStarter.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
  public void trigger(@NonNull Bundle jobBundle) {
                       ^
  symbol:   class NonNull
  location: class ReactNativeEventStarter
C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Projects\Getz New\app\node_modules\react-native-background-job\android\src\main\java\com\pilloxa\backgroundjob\BackgroundJobModule.java:146: error: cannot find symbol
  @Nullable @Override public Map<String, Object> getConstants() {
   ^
  symbol:   class Nullable
  location: class BackgroundJobModule
C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Projects\Getz New\app\node_modules\react-native-background-job\android\src\main\java\com\pilloxa\backgroundjob\ExactJob.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
  @Override protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
                                           ^
  symbol:   class Nullable
  location: class ExactJob
C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Projects\Getz New\app\node_modules\react-native-background-job\android\src\main\java\com\pilloxa\backgroundjob\Utils.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
  public static boolean isReactNativeAppInForeground(@NonNull ReactNativeHost reactNativeHost) {
                                                      ^
  symbol:   class NonNull
  location: class Utils
9 errors.
 What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-background-job:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'
```

Build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
ext {
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.3"
    }
 repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        // Specifically 3.0.1: concidered stable
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" } 
                maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }

}
```

Build.gradle/app:

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"


def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false


def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"


    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.dd.medworks"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 3
        versionName "2.1"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }

    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk true  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            manifestPlaceholders = [excludeSystemAlertWindowPermission: "true"]
        }
          debug {
            manifestPlaceholders = [excludeSystemAlertWindowPermission: "false"]
        } 
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
     lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
}

dependencies {
      //compile project(':react-native-background-task')
      compile(project(':react-native-svg')) {
        exclude group: "com.android.support", module: "appcompat-v7"
    }
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile project(':react-native-charts-wrapper')
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    compile files('libs/dnurseexttestlib.jar')
    compile 'me.tankery.lib:circularSeekBar:1.1.7'
    compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.3.0'
    compile project(':react-native-push-notification')
     compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:+'
      implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:+'
      compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:+'
    compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0') {
        force = false;
    }
    //       compile (project(':react-native-fcm')){
    //     exclude group: "com.google.firebase" 
    // }
    implementation project(':rn-fetch-blob')   
      compile project(':react-native-pdf')  
      compile project(':react-native-background-job') 
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to migrate in android X.

Do change in your library

Ex: android.support.annotation.NonNull change to androidx.annotation.NonNull

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

OR 
try this https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21722

Comment: Thanks for quick reply mate but when i am migrating to andriodx through studio alert box is popping "no usage found in the project"

Comment: android.enableJetifier: When set to true, the Android plugin automatically migrates existing third-party libraries to use AndroidX by rewriting their binaries. The flag is false by default if it is not specified.

Comment: hi @SajjadRaza even i am getting that pop up saying "no usage found in the project" have u resolved it?

Comment: Hi @Sathvik Nasani sorry for late reply , i had managed to resolve this issue it is  some sort of hack or something but it works for me,Problem was that in one of my dependencies(react-native-inappbrowser-reborn) was causing a problem due to which "annoation does not exist" error was occurring. So i just commentted (implementation 'com.facebook.infer.annotation:infer-annotation:+') which you will find in node_modules->react-native-inappbrowser-reborn->android->build.gradle. Maybe in your case some other dependency is causes a problem find it and then give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

After androidx , android.support has obsoleted , use androidx while importing instead off android.support in given node module path . Hope this will work